# How can I write new columns that is being generated after each iteration in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 38 columns that I am pre-processing one by one. The result of each column must be written in csv file. Every time I run the code, only last processed column is written in csv. How can I add each column one by one onto output file using pandas?

Here is my code:

def min_max(my_data1):

```
for j in range (38):
    count = 0+j
    #print(my_data1[count])
    #get the min and max for each cloumn
    min_col= min(my_data1[count])
    max_col= max(my_data1[count])
    #print('Min','|','Max')
    #print(min_col,'|',max_col)
    value= (my_data1[count]-min_col)/(max_col-min_col)
    #new_value= value.append(value)
    #print(new_value)

    #my= pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\minmax.csv',header=None, sep=",")
    df= pd.DataFrame(value)
    df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\minmax.csv', sep=',', na_rep='', float_format=None,header=True, index=True, index_label=None)
```

min_max(my_data1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont need loops, better is use pandas functions [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) and [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) and [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```
a = my_data1.sub(my_data1.min(axis=0))
b = my_data1.max(axis=0).sub(my_data1.min(axis=0))

df = a.div(b)
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(100)
my_data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,5)))
print (my_data1)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  8  8  3  7  7
1  0  4  2  5  2
2  2  2  1  0  8
```

---

And my solution:

```
a = my_data1.sub(my_data1.min(axis=0))
b = my_data1.max(axis=0).sub(my_data1.min(axis=0))

df = a.div(b)
print (df)
      0         1    2         3         4
0  1.00  1.000000  1.0  1.000000  0.833333
1  0.00  0.333333  0.5  0.714286  0.000000
2  0.25  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  1.000000
```

But if really need loop slowier solution append values to `list` and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
def min_max(my_data1):
    L = []
    for count in range (len(my_data1.columns)):
        min_col= my_data1[count].min()
        max_col= my_data1[count].max()
        value= (my_data1[count]-min_col) / (max_col-min_col)
        L.append(value)
    return pd.concat(L, axis=1)

df = min_max(my_data1)
print (df)
      0         1    2         3         4
0  1.00  1.000000  1.0  1.000000  0.833333
1  0.00  0.333333  0.5  0.714286  0.000000
2  0.25  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  1.000000
```

**Timings**:

```
In [334]: %timeit min_max(my_data1)
18.8 ms ± 257 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [335]: %timeit my_data1.sub(my_data1.min(axis=0)).div(my_data1.max(axis=0).sub(my_data1.min(axis=0)))
2.2 ms ± 39.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
np.random.seed(100)
my_data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000,38)))
print (my_data1.head())

def min_max(my_data1):
    L = []
    for count in range (len(my_data1.columns)):
        min_col= my_data1[count].min()
        max_col= my_data1[count].max()
        value= (my_data1[count]-min_col) / (max_col-min_col)
        L.append(value)
    return pd.concat(L, axis=1)

df1 = min_max(my_data1)
print (df1.head())

df2 = my_data1.sub(my_data1.min(axis=0)).div(my_data1.max(axis=0).sub(my_data1.min(axis=0)))
print (df2.head())
```

Comment: Thanks. This code made my actual code quite easily.